# Finding the explicit formula given recursion

Tags: recurrence-relations

This is the recursive formula:
$$\begin{cases}
a_1=1/2,\\
a_n= \sqrt {\frac {a_{n-1}+1}{2}}
\end{cases}$$

I have calculated the first 4 terms to be $\frac12, \frac {\sqrt3}2, \frac {\sqrt{\sqrt3+2}}2, \frac {\sqrt{\sqrt{\sqrt3+2}+2}}2$

How can I find the explicit formula?

Looking at the first 4 terms, I notice that the denominator remains at 2, while the numerator appears to also be recursive. I will call this numerator $b_n$
$$\begin{cases}
b_1=1,\\
b_n= \sqrt {b_{n-1}+2}
\end{cases}$$

I am thinking that if I find the explicit formula for $b_n$, perhaps I could use the formula $\frac {b_n}2=a_n$ and solve.

I also figure out that in the recursive formula where $c_1=x$, and $c_{n}=\sqrt{c_{n-1}}$, the explicit formula would be:
$$c_n=x^\frac1{2^{(n-1)}}$$

I am currently struggling on how to solve for the case $b_n=\sqrt{b_{n-1}+2}$

Comment: Can you elaborate more please?

Comment: Have you tried to compute the first values ? What does that give ?

Comment: If you want to sqare the sequence, it would go like this: $b_n = a_n^2 = \frac{a_{n-1} + 1}{2} = \frac{\sqrt{b_{n-1}} + 1}{2}$. It's not enough to square the recurrence formula. That's why your graph doesn't line up.

Answer (score 1):

Such non-linear recurrences very rarely have explicit solutions.

You can go for a limit, though: If the limit is $A$, it must be that:

$\begin{align*}
   A
     &= \sqrt{\frac{A + 1}{2}} \\
   A^2
     &= \frac{A + 1}{2} \\
   A
     &= \frac{1 \pm \sqrt{1 + 4 \cdot 2}}{4} \\
     &= 1 \text{ or } -\frac{1}{2}
\end{align*}$

The negative value makes no sense, so the limit (if it exists) is 1. To prove the limit exists, see that $a_n$ is strictly increasing, limited from above by 1.